# Make svn repository readonly with linux server and windows clients and no server access

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Given a standard SVN server on a GNU/linux host which I don't have admin permissions to, and clients that are all using windows, mostly through TortoiseSVN, I need to make one repository read only for all clients.

I understand I may be able to do this with a pre-commit hook but I couldn't seem to get it working so idiot proof instructions of how to apply this to the repository would be appreciated. Also note that all clients are on windows not *nix.

If possible it would be nice if clients who had already checked out (and so may not have updated to retrieve the new hook) were also blocked from writing to the repository but it may be that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block all and any commits from all clients

`pre-commit.sh` in `$ThisRepo/hooks` folder on SVN-server

```
#!/bin/bash  

 echo -e "Commits disabled." 1>&2  
 exit 1
```

Hook(s) are not part of repo, they exist outside it in physical folder on server-side

Comment: So commit that file inside a folder named hooks in the root of the repo? Or actually on the server - because i don't have access to the server

Comment: Also did you mean pre-commit?

Comment: No, you don't commit this file. You write it to the server itself. If you don't have access to the server, then you cannot accomplish what you want. Denying access to a server is a server-side configuration. There is nothing you can do client-side to deny access to the server.